# find all users that own files in a folder in Linux using bash

Tags: linux, bash, find

I am trying to find all the users that own files in a specific path. Right now I am using `find` with `sort` and `uniq` but if there are a lot of files/folders it can take a long time. I was wondering if there is a faster/better way?

```
$ sudo find / -xdev -type f -printf "%u\n" | sort | uniq

man
root
user1
user2
user3
```

Comment: Exclude `proc` and `sys` as well as any other directories off `'/'` like `run, srv` (or `www` on some) and `var` will cut down the time `find` spends spinning its wheels. There is no magic bullet here. `find` is the tool for that type of wide spread search. This sounds somewhat like an [**XY problem?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since you are sorting unique at the end. Why not just query `/etc/passwd` for unique users and supplement with `/etc/groups` or the like?

Comment: If you find yourself doing this often, perhaps run it as a weekly or monthly `cron` job.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You missed `-xdev`.

Comment: Uggh. Good catch. `srv` and `var` would be the only benefits then (and any other that could be excluded or pruned)

Comment: Using `/` was just for the sake of an example. In reality I'll be checking very specific paths. I guess I'll go with pulling users out of `/etc/passwd`. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If you put the `/etc/passwd` idea as an answer I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per you comment, when thinking of locations on a Linux/Unix system where a list of unique user ID's can be obtained more efficiently than running a `find` on `/` piped to `sort | uniq`, the system password file would be a much better source of the information.

For example to get a sorted unique list of all user accounts on the system you can use:

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort
```

or if you prefer `sed`, then

```
$ sed 's/:.*$//' /etc/passwd | sort
```

Either will be orders of magnitude faster that piping the results of `find` to `sort | uniq`.

Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Great. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure how this will produce a directory specific list. Won't it just list all the users?

Comment: Yes, it obtains the sorted list of unique user ID's from `/etc/passwd`. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Using your `find` command can be done in a "better way." Specifically since you are actually wanting the ownership of files as a user list but limited to a specific path. Your slash `/` after the find command is starting the search from the top. So you will the results of everything from the top down. (Those results may be close to just listing the users.)

You can either `cd` to a specific directory `cd /var/www/html/`

and run the same command replacing `/` with `.`

```
find . -xdev -type f -printf "%u\n" | sort | uniq
```

Or drop in the path.

```
find /var/www/html/ -xdev -type f -printf "%u\n" | sort | uniq
```

### Examples

Results at `/var/www/html` **10** users have files.
[image]

And `cd` into test directory. **6** users have files.
[image]